# Address Locator built in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 is invalid in ArcGIS Pro 3.0x

Tags: arcgis-pro, geocoding, address

A contractor delivered 40 address locators which were built in Desktop 10.7.  The flat locators read in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 as Invalid Locator.  The composite locators are valid, but do not work, because they are referencing invalid locators.

Based on Esri Community forums, I see that Locators built in Pro cannot be read in Desktop, but I do not see any mention of the opposite - except recommendations to rebuild locators in Pro from scratch.

I did attempt to build a few from scratch, but the locator styles have changed, so I don't want to guess, and misrepresent what was delivered.

Has anyone seen this issue, or any script which can "upgrade" address locators from Desktop to Pro?  Or a crosswalk between the old locator styles and the new ones?

Comment: I would suggest you reach out to you local esri distributor and raise this as a support case?